# Wordpress custom post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

i would like to use custom post_type in my wordpress plugin but i have a problem if i will access this post_type.

if i activate my plugin i can access the for example this:
http://wp.localhost/movie_reviews/movie_test/

Generall part of class

```
function __construct () {

  add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'my_int' ), 1 );

}

function my_int () { 

    add_filter( 'template_include', array(&$this, 'my_template' ), 10 );

    register_post_type( 'movie_reviews',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Movie Reviews', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'singular_name' => __('Movie Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Movie Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'edit' => __('Edit', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Movie Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'new_item' => __('New Movie Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'view' => __('View', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'view_item' => __('View Movie Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'search_items' => __('Search Movie Reviews', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'not_found' => __('No Movie Reviews found', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Movie Reviews found in Trash', $this->var_sTextdomain),
        'parent' => __('Parent Movie Review', $this->var_sTextdomain)
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'menu_position' => 15,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' ),
      'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
      'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'img/my_icon.png', __FILE__ ),
      'has_archive' => false,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie_reviews')
      )
    );

}

function my_template ( $template_path ) {

  if ( get_post_type() == 'movie_reviews' ) { 

        if ( is_single() ) {
          $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-movie_reviews.php';
        }

        // etc ...

  }

  return $template_path;

}
```

On activation hoock (part of the class)

```
function my_int () {

    register_post_type( 'movie_reviews',
      array(
          'labels' => array(
              'name' => __('Produkt Reviews', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'singular_name' => __('Produkt Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'add_new' => __('Add New', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'add_new_item' => __('Add New Produkt Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'edit' => __('Edit', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'edit_item' => __('Edit Produkt Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'new_item' => __('New Produkt Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'view' => __('View', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'view_item' => __('View Produkt Review', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'search_items' => __('Search Produkt Reviews', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'not_found' => __('No Produkt Reviews found', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Produkt Reviews found in Trash', $this->var_sTextdomain),
              'parent' => __('Parent Produkt Review', $this->var_sTextdomain)
          ),
          'public' => true,
          'menu_position' => 15,
          'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' ),
          'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
          'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/img/plugin.png', __FILE__ ),
          'has_archive' => true,
          'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie_reviews')
      )
    );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

// Edit: solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `has_archive` to `true` will display the post type archive at the location you mentioned.

OR you could leave it to `false` and create a page with slug `movie_reviews`

Make sure to visit the Permalinks settings page in your admin after you made the changes to flush the rewrite rules.